# $_GET and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom php file to a WordPress to do a simple action.

So far I have in my theme `index.php` file:

```
<a href="myfile.php?size=md">link</a>
```

and the php is

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>

<?php echo $_GET["size"]; ?>

<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

The link, once clicked, displays:

```
hello world
```

Is WordPress taking over the `$_GET` function and I need to do some tricks to use it? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

```
<?echo "hello world";?>
<? 
  if (array_key_exists('size', $_GET))
    echo $_GET['size'];
?>
<?echo "end";?>
```

Ouputs :

```
hello world
```

Comment: Are you passing anything in the variable?

Comment: Have you checked the server log for any errors?

Comment: @ian sorry the html was broken. Yes I'm passing a variable "size" with a value

Comment: Maybe php is not getting to your second <?> tag at all? Try combining all the code into 1 tag.

Comment: silly question, but are you sure you are viewing the results of your latest changes to the file and not a cached copy of the page or something? Change "hello world" to something else. (Sorry grasping at straws, but this happened to me before)

Comment: ahaha, the person that were doing the changes didn't changed the correct file. It's working now

Comment: peer programming fail ^^

Comment: That would be an "or something", can't tell you how many times i've done something like that. Glad you were able to figure it out in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will show anything but try turning on error reporting with:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', true);
?>
```

at the top of your page before any other code.

**Edit:**

From the OP comments:

> silly question, but are you sure you
> are viewing the results of your latest
> changes to the file and not a cached
> copy of the page or something? Change
> "hello world" to something else.
> (Sorry grasping at straws, but this
> happened to me before) – Zenshai
>
> ahaha, the person that
> were doing the changes didn't changed
> the correct file. It's working now –
> marcgg
>
> peer programming fail ^^ – marcgg
>
> That would be an "or something",
> can't tell you how many times i've
> done something like that. Glad you
> were able to figure it out in the end.
> – Zenshai

I usually discover errors like these only when they begin to defy everything I know about a language or an environment.

Answer (score 15):

See the solution :

In order to be able to add and work with your own custom query vars that you append to URLs, (eg: `www.site.com/some_page/?my_var=foo` - for example using `add_query_arg()`) you need to add them to the public query variables available to `WP_Query`. These are built up when `WP_Query` instantiates, but fortunately are passed through a filter `query_vars` before they are actually used to populate the `$query_vars` property of `WP_Query`.

For your case :

```
  function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
       $vars[] = "size";
       return $vars;
  }
  add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

and on your template page call the get methode like that :

```
$size_var = (get_query_var('size')) ? get_query_var('size') : false;
if($size_var){
   // etc...
}
```

**More at the Codex** : **http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var**

I hope it helps !

Comment: this isn't true, and a misunderstanding of what query variables are. Query variables and `get_query_var`/etc are for the arguments that `WP_Query` accepts, and rewrite rules. You shouldn't need to do this to use URL parameters, `$_GET` and `filter_input` should be working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?echo "hello world";?>
<? 
  if (array_key_exists('size', $_GET))
    echo $_GET['size'];
?>
<?echo "end";?>
```

If you see

```
hello worldend
```

... that means you're not setting the size GET parameter.  What URL are you using to access said page?

Comment: Try putting <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> at the top and see if you get any meaningful errors.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does not take $_GET over. Are you sure that you are passing the variable correctly?

If you hardcode the variable in a url, make sure it is of this form:

```
YOUR_SITE_PATH/?variable_name=variable_value
```

please not the "/" at the end of the url, before the "?"

I cannot see your index.php code,  but make sure that the variable "size" is either set manually in the url or from a submitted form. If you use a form, make sure that you use the method="GET". If you use method="POST", then your variable will be in $_POST['size'].

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think so, the path is : http://website.com/blog/fontSwitcher.php?size=md. I updated the index.php code

Comment: website.com/blog/fontSwitcher.php/?size=md doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at WP's documentation about the WP Query object.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview

It seems like wordpress uses the get_query_vars to method of the wp_query object to get queries.

You may also take a look at this one:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite old post it might be of good use to let know.... There is one plugin that can ease handling of $_GET, $_POST and global variable declaration issues pretty well. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-registry/

Answer (score 0):

May be this can somebody

Please check your htaccess file. and have a rewrite rule there

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase <<relative_url>>/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . <<relative_url>>/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please change << relative_url>> with the relative url as compared to your domain

I faced the same issue and my wordpress was installed on a godaddy server . But after changing the .htaccess file the issue got resloved.